# Implicit Differentiation of $xe^{tx} = C$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation

Show that any function $x=x(t)$ that satisfies the equation $xe^{tx} = C$ is a solution of the differential equation $(1+tx)x'=-x^2$. In the answer they state that you should Differentiate $xe^{tx} = C$ implicitly w.r.t. $t$. But I do not know how to do such an implicit Differentiation. Could someone help me out a bit?

Comment: Assume that the function $x(t)$ satisfies the relation $x(t)e^{tx(t)}=C$. Differentiate this relation in $t$.

Comment: Then I would assume that the derivative is equal to $x^2e^{tx} + x'e^{tx} + A$ where A is the part which is rather unclear to me. I know this derivative is not complete only I do not know how to complete it. I struggle to take the derivative of x(t) within the exponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

$$x(t)e^{tx(t)}=C$$

If we differentiate this with respect to $t$ then we get:

$$x'(t)e^{tx(t)}+(tx'(t)+x(t))x(t)e^{tx(t)}=0$$

Which implies that:

$$-x^2(t)=x'(t)(1+tx(t)).$$

Comment: Is the derivative of $x(t)e^{tx(t)}$ when taking the derivative of the upper x(t) (within the e) equal to $x(t)x'(t)e^{tx(t)}t$?

Comment: Remember to apply the chain rule!

Comment: I have used it right, the derivative of (wrt x(t) wihtin e) $x(t)e^{tx(t)}$ is itself times derivative of $(tx(t))' = tx'(t) \rightarrow x(t)e^{tx(t)}tx'(t)$ .

Comment: but $t$ is not a constant, you are forgetting that one.

Comment: I do not understand that to be honest we have this right: $d/dx_1 (x_1(t)e^{tx_2(t)}) = x_1'(t)e^{tx_2(t)}$. And that plus $d/dx_2 (x_1(t)e^{tx_2(t)}) = x_1(t)x_2'(t)te^{tx_2(t)}$ and as last $d/dt (x_1(t)e^{tx_2(t)}) = x_1(t)x_2(t)e^{tx_2(t)}$. Where I Used x_1 and x_2 just to make a distinction between derivatives.

Comment: Or is it just pure luck on my side that both these answers coincide?

Comment: Recall that you are interested in the derivative wrt to $t$, $x'=dx/dt$.

Comment: I think I still do not understand. Could you maybe break the full derivative up into terms?

Comment: Differentiate $a(t)e^{tb(t)}$ wrt $t$, then let $a(t)=b(t)=x(t)$. What do you get?

Comment: I would assume $a(t)b(t)e^{tb(t)}$

Comment: $e^{tb(t)}( a'(t)+a(t)[b(t)+tb'(t)])$ ... right?

Comment: I do not understand this sorry :(

Comment: It's a mystery to me which derivative I take first. And how this work regarding the x(t).

Comment: Let me give another try: $\frac d{dt} (x(t)e^{tx(t)})=x'(t)e^{tx(t)}+x(t)\frac d{dt} (e^{tx(t)})$ by the Leibniz rule. Now let us focus on the term $\frac d{dt} (e^{tx(t)})$ only: it is equal to $e^{tx(t)}\frac d{dt}(tx(t)) $ by the chain rule. Finally, $\frac d{dt}(tx(t))=x(t)+tx'(t)$, again by the Leibniz rule. Everywhere we derive with respect to $t$, and we denote $x'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}x(t)$.